# Algorithm for state inference from different time-point observation

Tags: r, algorithm, time-series, timeserieschart

I have recorded the changing of light emission of 15000 lamps over 1000 different time points. Now I have a matrix with lamps in the rows and time points in the columns, with intensity of light emission in the cells.

What kind of algorithm may I use to check if the lights follow kind of a regular time pattern or if they change stochastically?

Comment: You need to add some reproducible code in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited the title to incorporate that you're looking for an algorithm and set off the question from the introduction. You should probably mention if the intervals between the time points are fixed or irregular as right now it's ambiguous. I added `algorithm` to the tags, to wake up the algo monkeys. Good luck!